# iam getting Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to retail.model.vo.Book

Tags: java, generics, jpa

I am getting the exception below when type casting the list to a particular object. I think I'm doing it correctly. Can anyone suggest what is the wrong with the code?

```
SEVERE: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to retail.model.vo.Book
SEVERE:     at retail.ejb.service.ProductsSessionBeanImpl.showBookDetails(ProductsSessionBeanImpl.java:40)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
SEVERE:     at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
SEVERE:     at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:206)
SEVERE:     ... 54 more
```

```
@Override
        public List<Book> showBookDetails() {
            List<Book> book = em.createQuery("select p,b from Products p,Book b where p.productId=b.productId").getResultList();
            //PRODUCT,book where PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID = book.product_id
            System.out.println("List Size:::"+ book.size());
            //Customer obj = new Customer();
            List<Book> booksList = new ArrayList<Book>(); 
            for(int i=0; i<book.size();i++){




                Book books = (Book) book.get(i);
                System.out.println("Author ::::" + books.getAuthor() + "::ISBN ::"+books.getIsbnNumber()+"::pages::"+books.getNoOfpages()+"::price::"+books.getPrice()+
                        ":::description::"+books.getProductDesc() + "::product id ::"+books.getProductId()+"::title::"+books.getProductTitle()+"::Stock::"+books.getStock());
                booksList.add(books);
                //obj.setCustomerList(customersList);
            }
            return booksList;
        }

    }
```

```
package retail.model.vo;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="product_id")

public class Book extends Products implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4264546498700495061L;

    private String author;
    private String isbnNumber;
    private int noOfpages;
    private String illustrations;

    @Column(name = "author")
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    @Column(name = "isbn_number")
    public String getIsbnNumber() {
        return isbnNumber;
    }
    public void setIsbnNumber(String isbnNumber) {
        this.isbnNumber = isbnNumber;
    }

    @Column(name = "noof_pages")
    public int getNoOfpages() {
        return noOfpages;
    }
    public void setNoOfpages(int noOfpages) {
        this.noOfpages = noOfpages;
    }

    @Column(name = "illustrations")
    public String getIllustrations() {
        return illustrations;
    }
    public void setIllustrations(String illustrations) {
        this.illustrations = illustrations;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
em.createQuery("select p,b from Products p,Book b where p.productId=b.productId").getResultList();
```

actually returns a List of object arrays (`List<Object[]>`). The first element of the object array is a Product, and the second is a Book.

The compiler only complains with a warning in these cases because it doesn't know which generic type is returned from getResultList a priori. At runtime you don't get your ClassCastException at that line because of type erasure. The first actual cast of the `Object[]` in the `List` to the `Book` is done on the first list.get.

I guess the solution to your problem will be to change the query to:

```
List<Book> book = em.createQuery("select b from Products p,
 Book b where p.productId=b.productId").getResultList();
```

Which actually will return a valid List of Books.

Comment: You have a typo in your query. As it is currently written, it returns a list of Products.

Comment: @AleksanderBlomskøld Thanks for your replay, but i want to get both the details as product is parent table and book is child table which will inherit some properties from parent table. how can i do this

Answer (score 1):

createQuery return list of objects here

change

```
 List<Book> book = em.createQuery("select p,b from Products p,
 Book b where p.productId=b.productId").getResultList();
```

to

```
  List<Object[]> book = em.createQuery("select p,b from Products p,
 Book b where p.productId=b.productId").getResultList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your query is returning a list of `Object` arrays, the simply change this line:

```
List<Object> book = em.createQuery("select p,b from Products p,Book b where p.productId=b.productId").getResultList();
```

And as you making a cast in the loop it will be fine:

```
Book books = (Book) book.get(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for information,
I got same problem with Neo4j objects transform using Spring to java entity

I had named query:

```
 MATCH [bla-bla] RETURN a.name, a.associatedApplications
```

and the entity:

```
@QueryResult
@XmlRootElement
public class SomeDescriptor {
    @ResultColumn("a.name")
    private String name ;

    @ResultColumn("a.associatedApplications")
    private List<String> associatedApplications = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Same error:

```
    Neo4j java.lang.classcastexception: [ljava.lang.string; cannot be cast to java.lang.iterable
```

After I used Neo4j COLLECT() function, all was working fine!

Updated  named query:

```
 RETURN a.name, COLLECT(a.associatedApplications) as associatedApplications
```

and updated the entity:

```
@QueryResult
@XmlRootElement
public class SomeDescriptor {
    @ResultColumn("a.name")
    private String name ;

    @ResultColumn("associatedApplications")
    private List<String> associatedApplications = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```